# How can i display my background in html using css?

Tags: html, css

*html
//

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> StockAdi </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Cafe Adi" width="175" height="175">
            <h1> StockAdi </h1>
        </body>
    </html>
```

//
*css

```
body{
    background: linear-gradient (to left, #C09B30, #ffffff);
}
```

here is my code in my project, but it seems that it won't display the background that i want. What can i do?

Comment: For gradients, which can be tricky, its probably best to just use a page like https://cssgradient.io/ and apply their code to your body tag. Works every time.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you had an extra space behind `linear-gradient`, the syntax was invalid. Removing the space resolves your issue:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #C09B30, #ffffff);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Cafe Adi" width="175" height="175">
    <h1> StockAdi </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```